# RealVNC Viewer on Raspberry Boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vnc, vncviewer

I have a main Raspberry Pi in one room and a second one in other room. My software is running on the main Pi and i'd like the second one to just mirror the first one. RealVNC is fine, but i can't figure out how to make the second Pi (the one with Viewer) to connect automatically on startup. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `cron` job at boot might be enough for you. Execute `$crontab -e` and add following line:

```
@reboot export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/pi/VNC-Viewer-6.20.529-Linux-x64 192.168.xx.xx
```

- `@reboot` means, it's will execute on boot
- `export DISPLAY=:0` means, whatever GUI-program comes next, will bee on display `0`
- `/home/pi/VNC-Viewer-6.20.529-Linux-x64 192.168.xx.xx`, should start your VNC-viewer. (Perhaps read the `--help` first, I didn't have devices to confirm this one), also check the file-path!